# Integrity of Bitcoin transaction outputs

Tags: security, transaction-malleability

I am a noob. Currently, I am reading Mastering Bitcoin book. If I understand correctly, output of a bitcoin transaction is just a locking script with this format:

```
scriptPubKey: "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 (PubKHash of reciever) OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG"
```

My Question is: What prevents miners from modifying PubKHash section of the above script and changing it to their addresses and stealing bitcoins from sender?

Answer (score 2):

The outputs of a transaction are signed by the inputs. Changing the outputs would cause it to become invalid, and it would not be able to be included in a valid block.